# Magento catalogrule ID (rule_product_id ) to SKU (product ID)

Tags: magento

I search a way to get the product ID (SKU) from a rule_product_id.
The rule_product_id is the ID to a product in the catalogrule tables like: catalogrule_product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do a SQL-JOIN on the product entity table.

Comment: hmm looks like:
the catalog_product_entity.entity_id = catalogrule_product.product_id

thx